# Android sqlite database error SQLiteException

Tags: android, sqlite

i have error when i try to save in database it immediately crashes with the error SQLiteException: no such column. I'm stumped on what to do as SQLite is still very much a mystery to me.

Logcat:

```
03-29 01:04:29.823: E/SQLiteDatabase(23044): Error inserting ID=0 Y=15.085753686726093 X=26.93791172584063 description=Programmez pour Android nom=marker
03-29 01:04:29.823: E/SQLiteDatabase(23044): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: table_point: , while compiling: INSERT INTO table_point(ID,Y,X,description,nom) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)
03-29 01:04:29.823: E/SQLiteDatabase(23044):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
03-29 01:04:29.823: E/SQLiteDatabase(23044):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:64)
03-29 01:04:29.823: E/SQLiteDatabase(23044):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileSql(SQLiteProgram.java:177)
03-29 01:04:29.823: E/SQLiteDatabase(23044):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileAndbindAllArgs(SQLiteProgram.java:395)
03-29 01:04:29.823: E/SQLiteDatabase(23044):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.acquireAndLock(SQLiteStatement.java:263)
03-29 01:04:29.823: E/SQLiteDatabase(23044):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:115)
03-29 01:04:29.823: E/SQLiteDatabase(23044):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1718)
03-29 01:04:29.823: E/SQLiteDatabase(23044):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1591)
03-29 01:04:29.823: E/SQLiteDatabase(23044):    at tn.pfe.ybn.sigl.database.PointBDD.insertPoint(PointBDD.java:61)
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, your logcat says `no such table`. I believe this is because your `onCreate()` method is empty, so the table is never getting created. Update your code in `DbManager` as follows:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
{
    db.execSQL(CREATE_POINTS);
}
```

Also, you've got two different table names in your code. In `DbManager`:

```
private static final String TABLE_POINT = "point";
```

In `PointBDD`:

```
private static final String TABLE_POINT = "table_point";
```

Comment: Ok, which error? `no such table` or `no such column`?

Comment: no such table: table_point: , while compiling: INSERT INTO table_point(ID,Y,X,description,nom) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)

Comment: Check my edit. After you fix the table names, uninstall and reinstall again.

Comment: i fix it and change the name of TABLE_POINT ="ponit" and i uninstall and reinstall but the application still crashing

Comment: Has your logcat changed? If so, please edit your question to show the new info. If not, lemme know; I'll have another look.

Comment: Ok, if you're certain it's still a `no such table` error, at this point you should do some debugging. Add some break points at the critical spots, e.g. the table creation line, and make sure it actually is executing. You'll have to un/reinstall again to do so. Also, double-check the names again. Actually, it's better to use the same values in both spots. Delete them from one class, and use the values from the other.

Comment: i checked the storagedirectory and the path of the database and i dont found any DB created so i think the problem is on the creation of the SIGLOGIA.db

Comment: Actually, I think I might know what the problem is. Can you please post the code and class where you're calling `insertPoint()`?